# Python file throwing json decode error, how to adjust

Tags: python, web-scraping

This code keeps throwing an error, and I cannot get it to function to save to a text file. It keeps getting stuck at

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Python39\scrape2.py", line 32, in 
response = requests.get(url % page, headers=headers).json()
line 918, in json
raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] : 0

```
import requests
import json
page = 1
url = f"https://api-prod.grip.events/1/container/4368/search?search=&sort=name&order=asc&type_id=4907,4906,5265,4964,4904,1026,4908&page=%d"
headers = {
    'authority': 'api-prod.grip.events',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'accept-language': 'en-gb',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'if-none-match': 'W/"7132-A/vrxQVW3GqTDiJFLQqx9lN+Y0s"',
    'login-source': 'web',
    'origin': 'https://connect.money2020.com',
    'referer': 'https://connect.money2020.com/money2020europe/app/home/network/list/34589',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36',
    'x-authorization': 'a422cc2a-31fb-4b4e-a1bd-a34b561adc6c',
    'x-grip-version': 'Web/8.3.11',
}


s = requests.Session()

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)

with open("list.txt", "w") as f:
    for page in range(1, 1000):
        response = requests.get(url % page, headers=headers).json()
        contacts = response("data")
        for contact in contacts:
            target = "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (contact["company_name"], contact["job_title"], contact["name"],  contact["job_industry"])
            f.write(target + "\n")
            print(target)
```

Comment: The web server isn't returning json.

Comment: You create a session but never use it.

Comment: Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is returning HTTP code 304 (Not Modified) because the [`if-not-match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-None-Match) header already matches an ETag server-side (since this was presumably copied from browser devtools).

Just get rid of this header (and some other unnecessary ones), and fix the typo (`contacts = response["data"]`).

```py
import requests
import json

url = "https://api-prod.grip.events/1/container/4368/search?search=&sort=name&order=asc&type_id=4907,4906,5265,4964,4904,1026,4908&page=%d"
headers = {
    'x-authorization': 'a422cc2a-31fb-4b4e-a1bd-a34b561adc6c'
}
with open("list.txt", "w") as f:
    for page in range(1, 1000):
        response = requests.get(url % page, headers=headers).json()
        contacts = response["data"]
        for contact in contacts:
            target = "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (contact["company_name"], contact["job_title"], contact["name"],  contact["job_industry"])
            f.write(target + "\n")
            print(target)
```

You may also want to check out the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for writing TSV files.

Comment: No errors, but no results text?

with open('money.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['name', 'job_title', 'company_name']
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for page in range(1, 1000):
        response = requests.get(url % page, headers=headers).json()
        contacts = response["data"]
    for contact in contacts:
            target = "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (contact["company_name"], contact["job_title"], contact["name"],  contact["job_industry"])
    for row in reader:
            print((row['name'], row['job_title'],row['company_name']))

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the response is valid json? It could be receiving an error and you haven't handled that scenario.

Try updating it to the following and it should print any errors.

```py
with open("list.txt", "w") as f:
    for page in range(1, 1000):
        try:
            response = requests.get(url % page, headers=headers)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                response = response.json()
                contacts = response("data")
                for contact in contacts:
                    target = "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (contact["company_name"], contact["job_title"], contact["name"],  contact["job_industry"])
                    f.write(target + "\n")
                    print(target)
            else:
                print(f"Unsuccessful request: {response}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
```

Comment: a) This does not solve the issue b) How is this different from what is provided in the traceback?

Comment: Is there a solution to this that will help me get the json? Did I structure something incorrectly possibly?

Comment: @SuperStormer it will check if the response is 200 before trying to convert it to json() which will likely prevent the error.

Comment: That doesn't solve the root cause of the not-200 response.